# Mediaplayer does not work with Google Drive mediafiles

Tags: android, media-player, google-drive-api

I've developed two Android Apps for Google Drive. The Gallery App for image data is working perfect. My second App is a Musicplayer. Here I do have some problems with the download links Google Drive offers. An example:

This is a download link Google Drive offers for a MP3 file:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2hum21gMcbZaTJNMHIrbnJqSUk3aTFYb1pzOStyNjN3Z3ZnPQ&export=download&revision=true
```

When using this link in a browser the file is downloaded.

Usually I can feed a link like this into an Android Mediaplayer running in a Service (setDataSource). I do have a similar App that does this for Wuala media data - there it works exactly as expected. But it doesn't work for links returned by Google Drive.

```
player.id = newId;
player.status = PlayerObject.BUFFERING;
player.mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
player.mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
player.mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
player.mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
player.mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
player.mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(player.playlist.getUrl());
player.mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
I/StagefrightPlayer(116): setDataSource('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2hum21gMcbZaTJNMHIrbnJqSUk3aTFYb1pzOStyNjN3Z3ZnPQ&export=download&revision=true')
E/MediaPlayer(23964): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(23964): Error (1,-2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(23964): stop called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer(23964): error (-38, 0)
I/StagefrightPlayer(116): setDataSource('https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2hum21gMcbZUjlDUkRHV000d1JVZ2xDZVlIK25WY3ZEQzVRPQ&export=download&revision=true')
E/MediaPlayer(23964): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(23964): stop called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer(23964): error (-38, 0)
W/MediaPlayer(23964): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
W/MediaPlayer(23964): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
W/MediaPlayer(23964): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

Any idea what makes this link so special?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The link that fails is a public link (Who has the link has access...). So, no need to authenticate.

Comment: I'm facing same issue.Have you solved it?

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to authentication. This can be helpful for you: [REST API with HTTP Authentication](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/rest-api-with-http-authentication-android-beanstalk-example/).

Comment: Thanks for your link. What I forgot to mention is that this is a public available link (Who has the link has access ...). I can navigate thru the complete folder tree. It's just that I can't feed the download link into the mediaplayer - mediaplayer complaints about the link.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a same problem in android 2.3 (but after 3.0 ,is not a problem) is in setDataSource url link should be in http. but google drive offer https link.

Comment: This looks like a question/comment and not an answer.